# Is there a function in boost::test that can return error value?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

Boost Test Library is a very useful unit test framework. However, one thing I feel uncomfortable is that during the unit test if errors happen it will inform the user but not the program itself. Let me make my point clear by using BOOST_CHECK as an example:

```
i=3;
j=4;
BOOST_CHECK(i==j);
```

The above test case will fail. So, checking the details to find why this test fails will be very interesting. In this case, printing some variables or performing more complicated operations such as writing a file to the disk in the program will be necessary if it knows that the unit test fails. However, BOOST_CHECK will not return a value to denote the test is successful or not. A perfect function should work like this:

```
    i=3;
    j=4;
    if(Enhanced_BOOST_CHECK(i==j) == failed)
    {

        // print some internal varaibles.
        // or write some data to a file in the disk
     }
```

So my question is: does BOOST Test Library support this functionality? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost provides a macro `BOOST_WARN_MESSAGE` (and `BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE` and `BOOST_REQUIRE_MESSAGE` as well). In your case it could be used like this:

```
i=3;
j=4;

bool isEqual = i==j;

BOOST_CHECK(isEqual);
BOOST_WARN_MESSAGE(isEqual, "Failure since i = " << i << " and j = " << j);
```

Further info is found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/testing-tools/reference.html).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Printing variables may be enough by using BOOST_WARN_MESSAGE as you have suggested. But what if I want to perform more complicated task such as writing a file to the disk if the test fails.

Comment: I'm using a workaround for this: Any output of the test executable is redirected to a file anyways. This is all encapsulated in a batch file (OS is Win7). Would somthing like this be sufficient for you, too?

Comment: Good solution, but it works sometime. But what if I should write an image to a file?

Comment: @feelfree Writing an image to a file shouldn't be done while executing unit test code IMHO. It slows the test down. On the other hand the boost doc reads "The message argument can be constructed of components of any type supporting the std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&)." So it *is* possible if your image class can be pushed into an ostream.

Answer (score 1):

Boost Test offers a lot more than just `BOOST_CHECK`.

See [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/testing-tools/reference.html):

> The UTF testing tools reference
>
> ```
> BOOST_<level>
> BOOST_<level>_BITWISE_EQUAL
> BOOST_<level>_CLOSE
> BOOST_<level>_CLOSE_FRACTION
> BOOST_<level>_EQUAL
> BOOST_<level>_EQUAL_COLLECTION
> BOOST_<level>_EXCEPTION
> BOOST_<level>_GE
> BOOST_<level>_GT
> BOOST_<level>_LE
> BOOST_<level>_LT
> BOOST_<level>_MESSAGE
> BOOST_<level>_NE
> BOOST_<level>_NO_THROW
> BOOST_<level>_PREDICATE
> BOOST_<level>_SMALL
> BOOST_<level>_THROW
> BOOST_ERROR
> BOOST_FAIL
> BOOST_IS_DEFINED
> ```

You may want to use `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(i, j)` in your case.

Alternatively, looking at your second example, for more complex cases, you simply can do:

```
if (!(i==j)) {
  // Complex condition failed - report to boost test and add custom message
  std::string message = ...;
  BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE(false, message);
}
```